# What do I need installed in order to develop a site with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want to develop a web site using ASP.NET MVC but I’m not sure what software is needed for developing one.

For example, do I need Visual Studio? If yes, what edition? IIS? .NET Framework? Etc.

I’m looking for a clear list of what I need to install.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can start over here.

Welcome to .Net

[Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated!

Comment: This is probably also the best way to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can download Visual Studio Community edition 2015 
from https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx
It suppose to contain all need staff, also you can use IIS-Express build in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks - much appreciated!